# Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '1.654 x 2.34 x 3.430'

Tags: siunitx

when I tried to render the document in texlive 2023 with xelatex compiler:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \num{.3e45}\\
    \num{1.654 x 2.34 x 3.430}\\
    \si{\kilogram\metre\per\second}\\    
    \SIlist{0.13;0.67;0.80}{\milli\metre}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

shows error:

```
! Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '1.654 x 2.34 x 3.430'.
```

what should I do to fixed this issue? I have tried to tweak to * but still did not fixed this issue:

```
! Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '1.654 * 2.34 * 3.430'.
```

Comment: Why do you think that you can use `x` syntax in `\num`? The `siunitx` manal mentions `\numproduct` for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have v3 of `siunitx` which in contrast to v2 doesn't support products in `\num`. You need to use `\numproduct` for these cases:

```latex
\numproduct{1.654 x 2.34 x 3.430}
```